Aruco marker detection in Mathematica
Is there a ready made solution for Aruco marker detection in Mathematica? Aruco markers are similar to QR codes, but quite simpler, and quite commonly used for all kinds of detection tasks. Unfortunately, I don’t seem any resource functions to do this. There is plenty of software to do this in Python, Matlab, etc., but conspicuously missing in Mathematica unless I am missing something myself. Any pointers appreciated.

You could call Python routines from within Mathematica. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/Python.html

Hve you seen this? https://medium.com/@calle_4729/using-mathematica-to-detect-aruco-markers-197410223f62 This was the first hit when I googled "Aruco marker Mathematica".

I wrote the post that Henrik mentions. It's not perfect but it might work for you, depending on what you're trying to do.
